# OpenMM trying to run MD simulation

Tags: python, anaconda, openmmlab

The simulation failed with the following error:

invalid syntax (, line 36)

Details:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\CCL\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\openmmsetup\openmmsetup.py", line 388, in simulate
exec(script, {"output":output, "outputDir":outputDir})
File "", line 36
barostatInterval =
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I keep changing some of the parameter but nothing is working, is it possible its missing a file for it to run?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.